# using express-graphql server in reactnative?

Tags: react-native, graphql

I am new in graphql, would you please help me, I have a server for myself. I want to know may I use express-graphql for the server-side code and get query in a reactnative(mobile app) application through Apllo client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no problem using React Native as the frontend for your Express server. You can connect your GraphQL either with Apollo or Relay Modern. There are other options for server side, like Koa (http://koajs.com/)

GraphCool is also an easy to go platform to build your server: https://www.graph.cool/

You can find amazing tutorials here: https://www.howtographql.com/

This post is really good to get started too: https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/full-stack-react-graphql-tutorial-582ac8d24e3b

Or you can follow the official docs of Apollo GraphQL: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/

Or Learn Apollo docs: https://www.learnapollo.com/tutorial-react/react-01/

Hope it helps.